# How can I build custom air ducts for an in-wall heater?

Tags: heating, ducts, heater

I have a in-wall heater just like this one:

[image]
<sub>(source: [oly5star.com](http://oly5star.com/gfile/75r4!-!HILJJM!-!zrzor45!-!GEKOGEON-KLFH-HHDD-NKOF-OFOSIEOJMHHS!-!72y1nq/wall-heater.jpg))</sub>

It sucks cold air from lower part of vent, heats inside, and blows it out in the upper part of the vent.

Now I have the basic problem of putting a wooden cabinet in front of it. I can let the cabinet 8 inches away from the wall, but that doesn't solve my issue. The air stays hooked in that small region. The cabinet heats, which is not a problem. The problem is that the room stays cold!

What I really want is a different cover with a custom air ducts. I want the heater to suck air from the floor, heat it, and blow it straight to the top:

[image]

Is there an easy way to build these ducts myself? Remember the ducts must be heat-resistant!

Comment: You can create that using rigid duct found at big boxes - buy some snippers.  However I want to point out that your picture is 2D.  Meaning you show the air going up and down and it will really go out the sides (towards and away from the screen).  This isn't hard to do if you hillbilly it.  But to make it look nice is a different story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but the manufacturer of your heater would most likely prohibit the alteration of air flow into and out of the unit. Doing so would void the industry safety certifications required for manufacturers, the warranty, and would probably not be safe.

Additionally, all wall heaters have minimum clearance requirements for the placement of objects in front, 8" is likely too close for placement of combustibles (like wood cabinets).

I would recommend that you discontinue use of the wall heater if it does not fit your design plans. There are many types of plug-in electric room heaters that work for a variety of room sizes. Many of these are very quiet, inexpensive, and efficient (probably more efficient then that wall heater) and you can place it anywhere in the room you want.

Comment: Field alterations to this unit are most likely expressly forbidden by the manufacturer. Personally I'd just move the heater (cause I can do that) or the cabinet.